# Ansible - Best way to perform a local copy (in pre_tasks)?

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that requires to copy some files from a local directory into another local directory (on the ansible host). What is the correct way to achieve this?

I found the [`copy` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html) but it seems it is only for copying files to a remote host. I also found [`local_action`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html) but I'am very unsure how to use it.

The playbook looks something like:

```
---
- hosts: all
  vars:
    proprietary_files: "/some/files/not/managed/by/vcs"
    filesToWorkOnLater: "config_files"
  pre_tasks:
    - name "Copy from {{proprietary_files}} to {{filesToWorkOnLater}}"
   # What to enter here to perform the local copy?
   roles:
     ...   
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible now supports [import_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/import_role_module.html) so pre_tasks aren't needed anymore.
Something like this should fix you issue:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - command: cp file1 file2
    delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  - import_role:
      name: ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried delegate_to localhost? PLease try as below. (I have not tested)

```
  - name: copying to local
    copy:
     src: {{proprietary_files}}
     dest:  {{filesToWorkOnLater}}
    delegate_to: localhost
```