# Ansible - How to execute local commands with default user, not sudo?

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook that uses `become` to gain root access on the remote hosts using

```
become: yes
```

I also have some **pre_tasks** that have to run **local commands** at the **ansible host** in before.

How can I force this local tasks to be executed with the **default** user (the user that runs `ansible-playbook`)?

Here is my playbook (it is meant to perform a [local copy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58095568/1485527) operation as default user as a pre task):

```
---
- hosts: all
  vars:
    proprietary_files: "/some/files/not/managed/by/vcs"
    filesToWorkOnLater: "config_files"
  pre_tasks:
  - name: "Copy from {{proprietary_files}} to {{filesToWorkOnLater}}"
      local_action: 
         module: copy
         src: "{{proprietary_files}}/" 
         dest: "{{filesToWorkOnLater}}/"

  become: yes   
  roles:
     ...   
...
```

At the moment I'am getting complains from my local machine like

```
sudo: a password is required
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `command` with `delegate_to` and `become: no` instead of `local_action` works:

```
---
- hosts: all
  vars:
    proprietary_files: "/some/files/not/managed/by/vcs"
    filesToWorkOnLater: "config_files"
  pre_tasks:
    - name: "Copy from {{proprietary_files}} to {{filesToWorkOnLater}}"
      command: cp -r {{proprietary_files}}/ {{filesToWorkOnLater}}/
      delegate_to: localhost
      become: no

  become: yes   
  roles:
     ...   
...
```